# Find out which restaurants are open at a given time in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, time, case

There is an SQL table which shows the start_time and end_time of restaurants.
Some restaurants open before noon and close during the night.
But others open in the evening and close in the early morning.
I would like to find out which restaurants are open at a certain time.

The following code gives satisfactory answers in case of 24hour system.
But what is to be done in case of 12hour system with AM/PM ?

```
SELECT * FROM user_time WHERE 
(CASE
    WHEN user_time.start_time > user_time.end_time THEN 'currenttime' BETWEEN user_time.start_time AND user_time.end_time+24
    ELSE 'currenttime' BETWEEN user_time.start_time AND user_time.end_time
END);
```

In case of the following table and currenttime = 02:40 PM...

```
1   03:00 PM    01:30 AM
2   03:30 PM    02:00 AM
3   02:30 PM    02:00 AM
4   10:00 AM    09:00 PM
5   08:30 AM    09:30 PM
6   05:00 PM    11:00 PM
```

...result should be 3,4,5

Comment: Can you please tag the database that you are using?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: `user_time.end_time+24` is wrong, use `user_time.end_time + INTERVAL 24 HOUR`. *what is to be done in case of 12hour system with AM/PM ?* `start_time` and `end_time` are strings? Convert them to TIME datatype. You may do this in a query (use STR_TO_DATE), but the best way is to do this in a table.\

Comment: Are you sure INTERVAL 24 HOUR works? I've tried, but without result.   And start_time and end_time are not STRING, they're of DATETIME type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with boolean logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_time ut
WHERE ( -- start time is before end time so "between"
       ut.start_time < ut.end_time and
       current_time >= ur.start_time and
       current_time <= ut.end_time
      ) or
      ( -- start time is after end time so "not between"
       ut.start_time > ut.end_time and
       (current_time >= ut.start_time or
        current_time <= ur.end_time
       )
      );
```

The logic is to use `between` when start time is less than end time, and `not between` when start time is greater than end time.  However, the logic does not use `between` so that the start and end times are part of both ranges.

Comment: Let's suppose current_time is 5:00 AM and start_time, end_time is 4:00 PM, 6:00PM, respectively. In this case, the above code will return that the restaurant is open.                The Code still needs improvement.

Comment: @CharlieSchwab . . . Your comment does not seem correct.  5:00 a.m. is not later than 4:00 p.m.